# Add CSS blur to fancyBox2 background

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox-2

How can you add a css-blur on the whole page, below a clicked image in Fancybox2?
I mean a blur on the dark transparent background, not on the clicked image itself.

See example on http://jsfiddle.net/jRsjK/6867/ 
where I tried the (wrong) line

```
body '-webkit-filter' : 'blur(15px)'
```

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you mean something like this. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xW5gs/1195/).

**jQuery**

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        $("body *:not(.fancybox-overlay, .fancybox-overlay *)").addClass("blur");
    },
    afterClose: function () {
        $("body *:not(.fancybox-overlay, .fancybox-overlay *)").removeClass("blur");
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px)
}
```

As Martin Kovachev points out in the comments, this may be very resource-intensive on the CPU, and cause some delay and/or strange performance issues. Therefore, it can be useful to add hardware acceleration. Most often a 3D emulation technique is used where a 3D layer is added but not actually used, e.g. by setting `translateZ(0)` or `translate3D(0,0,0)`.

Comment: One thing - performance was HORRIBLE on a bigger resolution. What fixes it is to force hardware acceleration by simply adding: -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); after -webkit-filter:

Comment: @MartinKovachev Thanks for that. Edited post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xW5gs/1495/)

Just add the class blur to all elements outside the overlay and add a blur filter in CSS then you need an addtional SVG blur for Firefox.

jQuery

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        $("body *:not(.fancybox-overlay, .fancybox-overlay *)").addClass("blur");
    },
    afterClose: function () {
        $("body *:not(.fancybox-overlay, .fancybox-overlay *)").removeClass("blur");
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter:url(#blur-effect-2);
}
```

HTML (This is needed for Firefox)

```
<svg id="svg-image-blur">

    <filter id="blur-effect-2">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
    </filter>
</svg>
```

Comment: Awesome! Just what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

you can add some wrapper to add the filter like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

    <a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
</div>
```

js and then set the filter on afterload and remove it on afterclose

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterLoad:function(){
        $("#wrapper").css('-webkit-filter','blur(15px)');
    },
    afterClose:function(){
        $("#wrapper").css('-webkit-filter','');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jRsjK/6870/

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue, the blur is already in the fancybox function but if you are not seeing the blur then it is possibly because you don't have `fancybox_overlay.png` in your CSS folder.

This is a common mistake because after downloading the zip folder we only extract the CSS and JS and forget about the additional images that are in the zip folder. Goto inspect element and you can see it will show `fancybox_overlay.png` missing.

Answer (score -2):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/jRsjK/6868/)

Its already there in the fancybox

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

Comment: Question is about adding blur effect, not how to use fancybox. there is no blur effect in your example.